# How can I add an line number to my output and detect if a file isn't found?

Tags: java, filereader

I have code that is supposed to receive a filename from the user and output the contents in a numbered list like this:
https://imgur.com/a/CGd86xU

Now, I can't seem to be able to add the 1. 2. 3., etc into my output without hardcoding, or how I can try to detect if a file isn't found in the same directory as the code file is in and tell the user such file doesn't exist.

So far the code that I have output the code correctly as shown in the example but minus the numbering the content of the files or distinguishing if the file the user inputs exists.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter filename");
            String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
            File f = new File(fileName);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String readLine = null;
            System.out.println("");  //Intended to be empty as to allow the next line. So far that's the only way to get this part it to work.

            while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Note: I'm rather new to code involving files so yeah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to print line numbers for each line of the file specified by the user.

If so, then you can just add a `counter` variable when you read the file line by line:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter filename");
            String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
            File f = new File(fileName);

            if (!f.exists()) { 
                System.out.println(fileName + " doesn't exist!");
                return;
            }

            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String readLine = null;
            System.out.println("");  //Intended to be empty as to allow the next line. So far that's the only way to get this part it to work.

            int counter = 1;
            while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(counter + ": " + readLine);
                counter++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I also added a check to see if the `File` exists using the [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) method.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!